# Imprimir Funcion PHP en Query SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy teniendo problemas al imprimir una función de `PHP` en una consulta `SQL`. Tengo un formulario con un campo de `select multiple` que pasa los datos por `method` `$_GET`. 
Recibo esos datos y hago una función para poder hacer un `WHERE IN (1,2,3)` dentro de la consulta..

La función es:

```
$parametros=$_GET['parametros'];

function SectMultiple($var){ 
        for ($i=0;$i<count($var);$i++){
            $dato=$var[$i].",";
            echo $dato;
            }
        }
```

Si hago

```
SectMultiple($parametros);
imprime 1,2,3,4,
```

La `query` que intento hacer es esta

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE columna IN (".SectMultiple($parametros).")";
```

Los valores los imprime pero fuera de la `query`. 
Si hago

```
print_r($sql)
```

me devuelve

```
1,2,3,4
    SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE columna IN ()
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: Lo que estás tratando de hacer abre una vulnerabilidad de inyección de sql. NUNCA se deben formar cadenas usando valores que puedan ser ingresados por el usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás un poco confundido, `echo` es para imprimir la variable, sin embargo lo que tu necesitas es un `return` en tu función.

```
function SectMultiple($var){
    $dato = '';
    for ($i=0;$i<count($var);$i++){
        $dato=$var[$i].",";
    }
    return rtrim($dato, ',');
}
```

Entonces al hacer esto

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE columna IN (".SectMultiple($parametros).")";
```

ya lo imprimiría

PHP tiene una función llamada [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) que lo que hace es lo mismo que hace tu función, por lo que podrías hacer simplemente

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE columna IN (".implode($parametros).")";
```

También como te mencionaron en los comentarios, dejar que el usuario ingrese directamente la query no es buena opción, deberías echarle un vistazo a la librería de PDO de PHP

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me has ayudado mucho.. 
Lo había resuelto con join(',', array_map('intval',$parametros));, 
pero termine haciéndolo con implode(",",$parametros); como usted menciono.
Menos codigo, mismo resultado